# How to use raw SQL (DML and DDL) in Symfony projects?

Tags: sql, symfony

I'm new in programming and I've built projects on xampp. There I created the databases in SQL (MARIADB) in 2 separated files (DML and DDL).

Now, learning Symfony I found that looks like I must use ORM to create the database. Can't I just create DML and DDL and connect/upload them to Symfony instead of using ORM?

I've been 2 days looking for information on how to do that, and I've just found ORM documentation. I wish I just could do something like this function:

```
 function mod001_conectoBD () {
        $address= "localhost";
        $user= "root";
        $password= "";
        $database   = "projectDDL"; //(which I uploaded on phpmyadmin as projectDDL.sql)
        
        $link = mysqli_connect( $address, $user, $password, $database );
        
        if ( !$link ) {
            echo "Fail connection";
        } 
        return $link;
    }

    function mod001_disconnectBD ( $link ) {
        
        mysqli_close( $link );
    }
```

This ofc is just the example i used on my xampp project. With this I just used the uploaded projectDDL.sql and built the app around it. Thanks and sorry for my ignorance in this matter.

The reason why I want this is building composite Primary keys, and editting id names, which i find so difficult on symfony.

Imagine for example a table that requires 3 foreign keys and its own id to have a 4 fields primary key, dont know how to make that possible in Symfony.

Comment: This is kind of a big question and not really a good fit here but Doctrine's ORM layer depends a sql connection object very much like the one you are using.  It is called the [Database Abstraction Layer](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal/current.html)(DBAL).  In Symfony you can get the DBAL connection object just like you can get the entity manager and then run all the SQL you want.  Of course you might want to ask yourself why most Symfony developers use the ORM and maybe work through some of the examples in the docs before going off and doing your own thing.

Comment: Uhh, Ok I've seen some doc about DBAL, could be useful. Main reason why I'd like to do things on directly sql is there you can build easily composite primary keys. In my current project (which is extremely basic) I got comments table which's primary key is composed of userId + commentId + videoId and I believe is way easier to do that on SQL. Sorry if im annoying, Im too new to all of this. Thanks

Comment: The ORM does handle composite primary keys but they are a bit of a pain.  I drop down to sql all the time myself so by all means explore it.  Just keep in mind that out of the box you can get a DBAL connection object which works almost exactly like your $link object.  It is basically a thin wrapper over a PDO connection.  Just typehint against `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` and the connection will be injected.

Answer (score 0):

to connect symfony to mariadb you must modify the .env file which is at the root of your project, for your case it will give something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/projectDDL"
```

symfony takes care of creating the database for you, and for each table you have to create an entity

you can create your database with this command on the shell:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a primary key made up of several foreign keys, doctirne allows you to do that I have already used in a project, you create an entity with foreign keys from your tables and you specify at the beginning that it is also an ID, ex :

```
#[Id, ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]

#[Id, ManyToOne(targetEntity: Comment::class)]

#[Id, ManyToOne(targetEntity: Video::class)]
```

Documentation:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-1-dynamic-attributes